# How to sort search results in typeahead/bloodhound?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js, typeahead, bloodhound

I am using typeahead.js 0.11.1 and try to sort the results coming from a remote source. According to the code there should be the possibility to override the default sort function of bloodhound. But my sort function is never called. Same counts for the identify function.

Here is my code:

```
    var bloodhoundSearchEngine = new Bloodhound({
    // we do not need any tokenization cause this will be done on the server
    datumTokenizer : function(d) {
        return d;
    },
    queryTokenizer : function(q) {
        return q;
    },
    sorter : function(itemA, itemB) {
        console.log(itemA);
        if (itemA.count < itemB.count) {
            return -1;
        } else if (itemA.count > itemB.count) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return 0;
    },
    identify : function(item) {
        console.log(itemA);
        return item.value;
    },
    remote : {
        url : '/suggest/?term=%term',
        wildcard : '%term',
        transform : function(response) {
            return $.map(response.suggestItems, function(item) {
                return {
                    value : item.value,
                    count : item.count
                };
            });
        },
        rateLimitBy : 'debounce',
        rateLimitWait : 300
    }
});

$('#typeaheadinput .typeahead')
        .typeahead(
                {
                    hint : true,
                    highlight : true,
                    minLength : 1
                },
                {
                    name : 'existing-names',
                    display : 'value',
                    limit : 20,
                    source : bloodhoundSearchEngine.ttAdapter()
                });
```

Has anyone any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: can you please create a demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Have never tried jsfiddle.net but I have found a way to solve the problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The sorter is not invoked cause I use a custom transform function to transform the suggestions coming from the remote server. Therefore I included a call to the sorter in my transform function. The following code works for me:

```
var bloodhoundSearchEngine = new Bloodhound({
    // we do not need any tokenization cause this will be done on the server
    datumTokenizer : function(d) {
        return d;
    },
    queryTokenizer : function(q) {
        return q;
    },
    sorter : function(itemA, itemB) {
        console.log(itemA);
        if (itemA.count < itemB.count) {
            return -1;
        } else if (itemA.count > itemB.count) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return 0;
    },
    identify : function(item) {
        console.log(itemA);
        return item.value;
    },
    remote : {
        url : '/suggest/?term=%term',
        wildcard : '%term',
        transform : function(response) {
            return $.map(bloodhoundSearchEngine.sorter(response.suggestItems), function(item) {
                return {
                    value : item.value,
                    count : item.count
                };
            });
        },
        rateLimitBy : 'debounce',
        rateLimitWait : 300
    }
});

$('#typeaheadinput .typeahead')
        .typeahead(
                {
                    hint : true,
                    highlight : true,
                    minLength : 1
                },
                {
                    name : 'existing-names',
                    display : 'value',
                    limit : 20,
                    source : bloodhoundSearchEngine.ttAdapter()
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sorted` function was not getting called for me for some reason either, and thanks to [René](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758835/ren%C3%A9-reitmann) I was able to get it working.

```
var blood = new Bloodhound({
sorter: function(a, b) {
    var input_string = $(selector).val();
    distance = Levenshtein.get(a.name, input_string) - Levenshtein.get(b.name, input_string)
    return distance;
},
remote: {
    transform : function(response) {
        return blood.sorter(response)
    },
},
```